# Font: All And None

Tags: fonts

I am searching for a while this Font. 
It is in some document I have and I want to edit it. 
Does someone know how I could find this font?
I could not find it anywhere on the web, even where you can purchase some fonts.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We have nothing to do with purchasing/finding fonts.

Comment: see the answer... pffff

Answer (score 3):

Done it with [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/).

1. Load the PDF
2. Edit the Glyphs if needed
3. save and install....!!

Comment: I had the same issue and wasn't aware of this tool. This was very useful, thanks! :)

Comment: works, but somehow few characters can't be reproduced, instead of `c` a  different looking `c` is used